# An accessible proof that any fibre bundle is a fibration.

Tags: homotopy-theory

Are there an accessible proof that any fibre bundle is a fibration, that is, has the Covering Homotopy Property with respect to any (reasonable) space?
I don't want pathology, so the base space should be limited to be paracompact.

Huebsch's proof --> (https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969813?seq=1) uses Transfinite Induction (!), while Dold's proof --> (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Dold+partitions+of+unity+in+the+theory+of+fibrations&atb=v256-1&ia=web) brings in "numerability" to seek a maximum generality at the expense of extreme intricacy.

Comment: The proof that any locally trivial map has the HLP wrt every paracompact $T_2$ space is the same as the proof that any numerably trivial map is a Hurewicz fibration (there is no simplification by assuming paracompactness over numerability). The proof that every locally trivial map has the HLP wrt to each cube $I^n$ is not difficult. It is Proposition 4.48 in Hatcher's book (pg. 379). The proof that this is equivalent to having the HLP wrt all CW complexes is more difficult (I think it might also be in Hatcher's book).

Comment: I looked up Hatcher's book and found >Proposition 4.48. A fiber bundle p : E→B has the homotopy lifting property with respect to all CW pairs (X,A).   >A theorem of Huebsch and Hurewicz proved in §2.7 of [Spanier 1966] says that
fiber bundles over paracompact base spaces are fibrations, having the homotopy lifting
property with respect to all spaces.  >This stronger result is not often needed in
algebraic topology, however.     Thank you anyway for the information.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a short proof in [Auroux' notes.](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eauroux/215Bs12/05%20Fibrations.pdf) (page 4).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to read and transform into LaTeX.